# Javascript Promise.all - how to get value?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have the array of promises. I'm using `Promise.all` to handle them all. But how can I take the array of values from it? Something like:

```
const myValueArr = Promise.all(myPromiseArr);
```

Cannot find respective example.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `const myValueArr = await Promise.all(myPromiseArr);` or `Promise.all(myPromiseArr).then(myValueArr => { ... });`.

Comment: First non-ad-supported hit on DuckDuckGo.com: [*`Promise.all` on MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). With examples.

Comment: A [simple google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+how+to+get+result+of+promise.all) would have immediately given you the solution.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I love how you specified "non-ad-supported hit", lol.

Comment: @briosheje - Well, the ad-supported one was for a film called "Promises, Promises" so... ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately what I found was exactly as in both answers to my question. Not the thing I've needed. Big thanks to @Paulpro for answering my question. Unfortunately, I cannot mark the comment as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

The array of values will be the resolved value of the promise returned by calling `Promise.all`.

You get that value as you would the value of any promise resolution:

```
myValueArr.then( function (array_of_values) {
     do_something_with( array_of_values );
});
```

… or use `async` and `await`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the then function to get the values as:

```
Promise.all(myPromiseArr).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
```